# Prove by induction that $7a + 10b$ can represent all integers $n \ge 54$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

How do you use proof by induction to prove that $7a + 10b$ can  represent all integers $n \ge 54$ given that $a$ and $b$ are both positive integers?

Base Case is true because $7  \cdot 2 + 10 \cdot 4 = 14 + 40 = 54$.
Then I don't know how to set up the induction step.

Comment: You only need to check you can make $54$, $55$, $56$, $57$, $58$, $59$, $60$ as from these you can add a multiple of $7$ to get any other integer larger than $54$.

Comment: I recommend this article, if you're interested: http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2013-08

Comment: See also this question (read the comment directly under it): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/968005/how-to-prove-the-following-expression

Answer (score 1):

Considering the requirement that you must use induction.  Assume a number $n >53$, and $n=7k1+10k2$.

Consider $N=7K1+10K2$ with $K1=k1+3$ and $K2=k2-2$ so that

$N=7(k1+3)+10(k2-2)=7k1+10k2+21-20=n+1$

You then need to show that there is a combination for 54 and that that k2>2 for this combination (=your base case) so that the factors are all positive.